# Selecting specific child of a table class

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am scraping a website and there is a table of values held in a table class,
I am trying to get the third row of the table but I'm not sure how to specifically select that one and not the others.

[image: Picture of HTML]

Comment: Hi, to help you further, please post a [mcve] question.

Comment: get all to list `all_rows` and later use `all_rows[2]`

Comment: with xpath it could be `'//table[@class="table table-hover"]/tr[3]'` or maybe `'(//table[@class="table table-hover"]/tr)[3]'`

Comment: please include your code and you can use the snippet tool via [edit] to insert html we can copy